# Loading a graph to Neo4j from a csv file. issue: "Couldn't load the external resource"

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I'm using Neo4j 3.3.0 on Ubuntu, which is hosted (via virtual box) on Windows.

I've tried the below Cypher query. The data (more than 30000 rows) contains 3 columns as text-relation-text. However, it says

> Couldn't load the external resource at
>   file:///home/bharath/Desktop/neo4j/node_relations.csv

Data:

```
abandon, Antonym, maintain
abapical, Antonym, apical
abase, Antonym, exalt
```

Code:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
"file:///home/bharath/Desktop/neo4j/node_relations.csv" AS line 
FIELDTERMINATOR ','
CREATE (t1:node1 {text: line[0] }),
(t2:node2 {text: line[2] }),
(r:rel {text: line[1]}),
(t1)-[:r]->(t2)
RETURN line
LIMIT 5;
```

I'm looking for some help regarding this, any other approach? or do I have to change the query? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try coping your file to the import directory and using:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///node_relations.csv" AS line 
(...)
```

The import directory for linux installations is `<neo4j-home>/import` or `/var/lib/neo4j/import` if you are using a Debian package.

Take a look in the [file location docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/).

Comment: While i tried to copy to the specified location, i got 
    "Cannot create regular file /var/lib/neo4j/import/node_relations.csv : 
    Permission Denied"

Code:
    cp home/bharath/Desktop/neo4j/node_relations.csv 
    /var/lib/neo4j/import

So, I've tried to change the permissions using 'chmod 755', but it still failed saying "Operation not permitted"

Comment: @BharathVarma yes, you will need sudo privileges to copy to this directory. If you have not,  add the line `dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true` o `neo4j.conf` and restart Neo4j.

Comment: @BharathVarma after restart, try importing using `"file:///home/bharath/Desktop/neo4j/node_relations.csv" AS line`

Comment: I understood. But even to modify(or uncomment) the line in neo4j.conf, it says permission denied.
file is at: /etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf

Comment: @BharathVarma Yes, you are right! You will need root privileges to change Neo4j configuration.

Comment: @BharathVarma you does not have these credentials?